# База данных для мультиязычного контента

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, yii2

Всем привет! Есть задача создать сайт, статьи на котором будут на разных языках. Как лучше спроектировать базу данных для такой задачи? Необходима высокая производительность.
Я себе представляю это так. Условно возьмём за переводимую таблицу posts с полями name, text, author, create_time. Для того, чтобы сделать мультиязычные статьи:

1. Создаём таблицу posts_lang с полями post_id, lang, name, text.
2. Из таблицы posts соответственно удаляем name, text.

Как мне кажется такая структура прозрачна, удобна и легко расширяема если добавляется новый язык.
Но вероятно, такая архитектура при большом количестве статей будет проблемой для производительности? Может у кого есть опыт? Может есть какие-то более крутые способы решения данной задачи?

Comment: сколько миллионов статей вы планируете хранить?

Comment: пока неизвестно, но я думаю в первое время 500-700 тысяч будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, откуда взялась идея про проблемы с производительностью.

Предложенный вариант предполагает связь по простому ключу, post_id+lang. Нужные поля находятся мгновенно через индекс и цепляются к основной выборке через джойн. Ничего более стандартного и производительного придумать в принципе невозможно.

Главное не забыть сделать индекс на post_id,lang именно в таком порядке. Хотя на самом деле даже индекса на post_id будет вполне достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо! Я на всякий случай спрашиваю, вдруг есть что посоветовать у кого был опыт.